# c# networkstream readasync() freezes after disconnection on windows mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, compact-framework, tcpclient, asyncsocket

I have a problem with the networkstream readasync() method. Normally when I create tcpclient in vs2012 and connect with the server, it throws a "connection closed" exception after I disconnect the client. However when I connect using motorola scanner (runs on windows mobile 6.5; app was compiled using vs 2008 using compact framework 3.5) and then close the tcpclient,  the server just freezes.

I would expect it to throw an exception, but when I use compact framework 3.5 it just doesn't.

This is the line it gets stuck on (inside the `try`) :

```
while(condition)
{
    try
    {                        
        _amountRead = await _stream.ReadAsync(
                _receiveBuffer, 
                _amountRead, 
                _amountExpected);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        _ex.Report(e, "stream read async"); 
        break; 
    }
}
```

Do you know what could be the problem?